# Using static method in Grails / GORM findAll closure

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.2, grails-2.5

I'm upgrading a Grails app from 2.2.4 to 2.5.0, and from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.

There is an existing GORM `findAll` query that passes a `java.util.Date` property (named `start`) of the domain object to a call to a static method that returns a copy of the `Date` with the time component stripped out.

Here's a simplified version of the `findAll` call (excluding criteria other than the one that throws the exception):

```
Reservation.findAll {
    DateUtils.justDate(start) == DateUtils.justDateToday()
}
```

This runs without any exceptions in 2.2.4, but, in 2.5.0, it throws a `GroovyCastException` saying that `start` is a `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria`, and cannot be cast to `java.util.Date`.

How can I get the query to work?

I could use something like:

```
Reservation.findAll {
    start >= DateUtils.justDateToday() &&
    start <  DateUtils.justDateTomorrow()
}
```

But that seems inelegant.  Also, domain object properties might be used as arguments to static methods in other `findAll` closures, so a generic solution to this issue will still be useful.

Comment: You have to also show how `start` is orchestrated to figure out why does it complain about it being a `DetachedCriteria`

Comment: What do you mean by "how `start` is orchestrated"?  `start` is a standard GORM domain object property, declared like: `Date start`.  Is that the info you're looking for?

Comment: `start` also has the following GORM constraint: `start validator: { val, obj -> !val || !obj.end || val < obj.end }`, but I doubt that a validator should affect read usage in a `findAll` closure.

Comment: Yes now I get it. I believe you cannot use utilities on domain properties like that. Refer my answer for a viable option/alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `where` query you can use methods like `date()`, `month()` and `year()` as below:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*
Date today = new Date()

Reservation.where {
    year(start) == today[YEAR] &&
        month(start) == today[MONTH] &&
            day(start) == today[DAY_OF_MONTH]
}.list()
```